# MySQL: Keep first occurrence row by id + first change value in column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to extract 1) the first occurrence of a risk score and 2) any changes in risk score within an individual in MySQL. Given the following table,

| rn | ID | Risk_Score | Recorded_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2022-03-01 00:01:00.000 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2022-03-02 12:01:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2022-03-03 23:01:00.000 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2022-03-04 17:02:00.000 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 2022-03-23 07:01:00.000 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 2022-03-23 11:01:00.000 |
| 7 | 3 | 0 | 2022-03-01 00:01:00.000 |
| 8 | 3 | 0 | 2022-03-03 04:01:00.000 |
| 9 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-03 14:01:00.000 |
| 10 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-04 06:01:00.000 |
| 11 | 3 | 0 | 2022-03-04 17:02:00.000 |
| 12 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-05 05:02:00.000 |
| 13 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-06 14:02:00.000 |
| 14 | 3 | 0 | 2022-03-07 02:02:00.000 |
| 15 | 3 | 0 | 2022-03-11 09:02:00.000 |
| 16 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-13 19:01:00.000 |
| 17 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-15 22:01:00.000 |
| 18 | 3 | 3 | 2022-03-18 18:01:00.000 |
| 19 | 3 | 3 | 2022-03-19 14:01:00.000 |
| 20 | 3 | 1 | 2022-03-19 19:01:00.000 |

My output needs to be:

| ID | Risk_Score | Recorded_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-03-01 00:01:00.000 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-03-03 23:01:00.000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-03-23 07:01:00.000 |
| 3 | 0 | 2022-03-01 00:01:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-03-03 14:01:00.000 |
| 3 | 0 | 2022-03-04 17:02:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-03-05 05:02:00.000 |
| 3 | 0 | 2022-03-07 02:02:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-03-13 19:01:00.000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-03-18 18:01:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-03-19 19:01:00.000 |

I tried the following codes:

```
CREATE TABLE test_run2
(
rn int,
ID1 int,
Risk_Score int,
Recorded_Time timestamp
);

INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (1, 1, 0, '2022-03-01 00:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (2, 1, 0, '2022-03-02 12:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (3, 1, 1, '2022-03-03 23:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (4, 1, 1, '2022-03-04 17:02:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (5, 2, 1, '2022-03-23 07:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (6, 2, 1, '2022-03-23 11:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (7, 3, 0, '2022-03-01 00:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (8, 3, 0, '2022-03-03 04:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (9, 3, 1, '2022-03-03 14:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (10, 3, 1, '2022-03-04 06:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (11, 3, 0, '2022-03-04 17:02:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (12, 3, 1, '2022-03-05 05:02:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (13, 3, 1, '2022-03-06 14:02:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (14, 3, 0, '2022-03-07 02:02:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (15, 3, 0, '2022-03-11 09:02:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (16, 3, 1, '2022-03-13 19:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (17, 3, 1, '2022-03-15 22:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (18, 3, 3, '2022-03-18 18:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (19, 3, 3, '2022-03-19 14:01:00.000');
INSERT INTO test_run2 (rn, ID1, RISK_SCORE, RECORDED_TIME) VALUES (20, 3, 1, '2022-03-19 19:01:00.000');

SELECT * FROM test_run2;

SELECT test_run2.ID1, 
        test_run2.Risk_Score, 
        test_run2.Recorded_Time 

    FROM test_run2 
                                            
    INNER JOIN test_run2 AS y
        ON test_run2.rn = y.rn + 1
        AND test_run2.Risk_Score <> y.Risk_Score
            
    ORDER BY ID1;
```

But the results were missing the following outputs:

| ID | Risk_Score | Recorded_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2022-03-01 00:01:00.000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-03-23 07:01:00.000 |

What should I do to ensure that all relevant points are extracted? I'm new to mySQL and will appreciate any advice on my issue. Thank you.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish change and if no previous row exists

```
select * 
from t
where (Select risk_score from t t1 where t1.id1 = t.id1 and t1.rn < t.rn order by t1.rn desc limit 1) is null or
      t.risk_score <> (Select risk_score from t t1 where t1.id1 = t.id1 and t1.rn < t.rn order by t1.rn desc limit 1)
;

+------+------+------------+---------------------+
| rn   | ID1  | Risk_Score | Recorded_Time       |
+------+------+------------+---------------------+
|    1 |    1 |          0 | 2022-03-01 00:01:00 |
|    3 |    1 |          1 | 2022-03-03 23:01:00 |
|    5 |    2 |          1 | 2022-03-23 07:01:00 |
|    7 |    3 |          0 | 2022-03-01 00:01:00 |
|    9 |    3 |          1 | 2022-03-03 14:01:00 |
|   11 |    3 |          0 | 2022-03-04 17:02:00 |
|   12 |    3 |          1 | 2022-03-05 05:02:00 |
|   14 |    3 |          0 | 2022-03-07 02:02:00 |
|   16 |    3 |          1 | 2022-03-13 19:01:00 |
|   18 |    3 |          3 | 2022-03-18 18:01:00 |
|   20 |    3 |          1 | 2022-03-19 19:01:00 |
+------+------+------------+---------------------+
11 rows in set (0.021 sec)
```

If you have version 8 or above

```
with cte as 
(Select t.*, lag(risk_score) over (partition by id1 order by rn) prev from t)
select * from cte where prev is null or risk_score <> prev
```

Comment: The version 8 or above codes works perfectly! Thanks so much. Really appreciate your advice.